# Can we render objects into html (ng-repeat) after certain limit can we continue to render from that last object to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to render the list candidate profiles as coursel (items) sliders(limit to 18 per slide).

This is my html:

```
    <div class="carousel slide management-item-carousel" id="hstlCandidateProfiles">
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="mngCourselInner">
        <div class="item active" data-interval="30" id="idFstItem">
            <div class="col-md-2 clsCndPrfImg" ng-repeat="Candidate in CandidateProfiles | limitTo:18">
                <a href="#/CandidatesProfile" ng-click="show(Candidate.ID)">
                    <img src="http://www.africaolympic.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/default-user.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle" />
                    <div class="col-md-12 clsCandidateName">{{Candidate.Name}}</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#hstlCandidateProfiles" data-slide="prev"><i
            class="icon-prev"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#hstlCandidateProfiles" data-slide="next"><i
            class="icon-next"></i></a>
</div>
```

From ajax call i will get list of candidate profiles  --"CandidateProfiles "

Angular code:

```
ManagmentApp.controller("cntrlrCandidateProfile", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "HostelManagementService", "$filter", "ModalService", function ($scope, $routeParams, HostelManagementService, $filter, ModalService) {

function getCandidateProfiles(response) {

    $scope.CandidateProfiles = response.data.CandidateData;
}
function errorTOGetCandidateProfiles() {


}
// ----------------Coursel slides initialization  ---------------------
function courselInitialisation(className, slideDuration) {
    $(className).carousel({
        interval: slideDuration //changes the speed
    })
}
courselInitialisation("#hstlCandidateProfiles", 3000);
HostelManagementService.get().then(getCandidateProfiles, errorTOGetCandidateProfiles);)};
```

Here I want to do after limit -18 candidate profiles reached then from 19 profile should bind as new "item" class.

```
 <div class="item active" data-interval="30" id="idFstItem">
        <div class="col-md-2 clsCndPrfImg" ng-repeat="Candidate in CandidateProfiles | limitTo:18">
            <a href="#/CandidatesProfile" ng-click="show(Candidate.ID)">
                <img src="http://www.africaolympic.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/default-user.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle" />
                <div class="col-md-12 clsCandidateName">{{Candidate.Name}}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After every 18 candidates it should bind new item(div element should render into the html).
Please help me....

Comment: Essentially, you would like to show only 18 of n items, then, dynamically showing others?

Comment: Actually I would like to show the 18 objects from array.
Array will be like this: [{},{},{}.......... n]
Every 18 objects i should show as one item(slide)

Comment: So you want to split your array every 18 items, right?

Comment: Yes- but every 18 objects should bind to div element(which has item class from above code).

Comment: All item class divs should be sibilings.

Comment: If you can provide a plnkr **only** with the relevant code will be better. It'll help to understand better your question.

Comment: This fiddle link : [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/ojs5jtnj/)
Here assume "HostelManagementService"  giving some array of objecs

Comment: You need to "make" a new `div` in after every 18 elements? So you need to use a directive for this.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
Can you please show me how to generate dynamic html in the directive.